# iOS Settings Bundle: Settings preserved on app upgrade?

Tags: ios, ios5

quick question: I'm considering using an iOs Settings bundle. I understand that those settings are stored in the user defaults. I assume when I upgrade my app, the app settings are preserved, correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Answer.

The NSUserDefaults settings persists on app upgrade.

[Do NSUserDefaults persist through an Update to an app in the Appstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638766/do-nsuserdefaults-persist-through-an-update-to-an-app-in-the-appstore)