# Do NSUserDefaults persist when installing a new build through Testflight?

Tags: ios, persistence, nsuserdefaults, testflight

User defaults persist between regular updates, but what about between Testflight builds? I'm guessing they do, but it is a test environment after all.

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1638766/220820), but not the same.

I would have tested this myself but my phone is being held for ransom at a repair shop, and I'm about to invite external testers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the NSUserDefaults persist if you install the app "over" the old one