# NSUserdefaults gets cleared when app updates

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, testflight

I have an app I've made for a customer which stores certain information in `NSUserDefaults` and it all works between sessions using the app. But when the user updates the app the `NSUserDefaults` gets cleared. As far as I can tell the `NSUserDefaults` should **NOT** clear on updates - only on uninstalls. I can't for the life of me figure out why or how to adress this issue.

My app is written in `Swift 2.0`, supporting iOS 8 and upwards, distributed through TestFlight and/or HockeyApp.

Comment: possible duplication of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638766/do-nsuserdefaults-persist-through-an-update-to-an-app-in-the-appstore

Comment: and, yes, the userDefaults should be persisted

Comment: Are you possibly (re)setting the NSUserDefaults when the app is launched for the first time ? That might explain why the older values don't persist.

Comment: first could you please clarify it is a public _update_ via AppStore or only a _new test version_ via TestFlight?

Comment: I will double check the setting of NSUserDefault at first time start, but I'm pretty sure this isn't the issue. I check at launch if the NSUserDefaults has data stored, if it does I load it in and just keep appending to it. If it doesn't exist I will store anew.

@holex New test version through TestFlight, not an update through AppStore.

Comment: @ClockWise, as you probably know that via TestFlight there is no such thing _"update"_, the TestFlight always does a clean install for security reason, regardless an earlier version of the app was/wasn't already on the device – and that includes to clean the `NSUserDefault` as well.

Comment: @holex thanks for your response, I'm not the one actually deploying the app so I'm not sure how TestFlight works, so thanks for clearing this up. Do you know it it's the same thing using Hockey App?

Comment: HockeyApp uses the OTA Ad-Hoc distribution mechanism from iOS. Downloading and installing the app is fully controlled by iOS itself. As far as I know this does not delete all user data prio to installation, but as the specifics on how iOS handles things (even differently in iOS versions) this can not be guaranteed.

Comment: @holex - NSUserDefaults should not be erased on TestFlight app update as far as I know. It's not getting deleted for me.

Comment: @Lubos, the keychain should not be deleted only.

Comment: @ClockWise Change in entitlement file also cause such kind of issue. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html

Comment: @BhaveshPatel Where are you seeing that exactly?